# Bash script is not asking for user input?

Tags: bash

I have this bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls "$SOURCE" > cplist.txt
cat cplist.txt | while read FILE; do
    echo "Would you like to copy $FILE? y/n"
    read ANSWER
    if [ "$ANSWER" = "y" ]; then
        cp -v "$FILE" ./Destination;
    else
        echo "File NOT coppied"
    fi
done
```

The idea is to make a list of all files in a folder, then ask the user each file they want to copy to the destination folder. Currently this script wont allow user input after: "would you like to copy $file? y/n". I cant work out why as I'm very new to this kind of thing. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run into problems as you're using two separate calls to `read` but you're making things more complicated than they need to be. Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$source"/*; do
    echo "Would you like to copy $file? y/n"
    read -r answer
    if [ "$answer" = "y" ]; then
        cp -v "$file" ./Destination;
    else
        echo "File NOT copied"
    fi
done
```

Instead of parsing `ls` (which is [generally considered a cardinal sin](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)), this uses the shell's built-in glob expansion to match everything in the directory `$source`. I have added the `-r` switch to `read`, which is [a good idea in general](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read#read_without_-r). I have also made your variable names lowercase. Uppercase variables should be reserved for built-in variables such as `$PATH`, which you certainly don't want to ever accidentally overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

You make the cplist.txt to the remaining part's standard input where the read tries to read from.